# openair function windRose() and I keep getting an error (seems to be related to column names maybe

Tags: r, openair, rose-plot

I am trying to create a windrose using the `windRose()` function in the `openair` package in R.

My data is in a dataframe called "data" which I uploaded from a .csv as as follows:

```
  ws             wd
  48.73114346    283.0710393
  61.49549084    243.7564505
  58.09342342    247.352044
  51.67627266    239.3605634
  19.52216981    304.2319862
  35.84687489    247.7485105
  39.84257171    284.7447041
  8.746914352    272.7665055
  32.43617745    289.2658996
  73.99142206    219.3024352
  62.94058264    269.3222006
  36.26804775    209.7422713
```

my code is windRose(data)

but keep getting the following error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
> x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
> x Column `default` doesn't exist.
> i Input `..1` is `across(type)`.
> i The error occurred in group 1: default = "all data".

I have tried specifying the column names so windRose(data, ws = "ws", wd = "wd") but this made no difference.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I am not getting any error. Can you please rerun the code after reopening the R session?

Comment: I have just restarted R and i am still getting the same error

Comment: OK so I have just tried to do the same code on my office computer and it worked. So I guess the problem is related to my R version being older maybe.